# Issue with mintTo function

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, token, mint, javascript

I tried to run the script below but got this error and was wondering where I may have made a mistake?

```
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
The token was created, here is the address: 7RELwCrQm1XZa7BtpAQbYUxrMmpssy2MF4TkvY1YE2kQ
Created an account for the owner of the token, here is the account AGe3KSgfyxhM3R6MNextG4MTCXs9nM4H4CoK9Eu7cG2r
Initially the account had 0 tokens
The account has 10000000000000 tokens after minting
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBuffer')
PS C:\Users\Student\Documents\Creating_SPL_Token\Solana_Token>
```

```
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey, amount } = require('@solana/web3.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const base58 = require('bs58');

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

const privateKey = base58.decode(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(privateKey);

async function fundWallet() {
    const signature = await connection.requestAirdrop(wallet.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature })
}

async function getAccountBalance(accountAddress) {
    const tokenAccountInfo = await getAccount(connection, accountAddress);
    return tokenAccountInfo.amount;
}

async function transferTokens(recipient, token, fromTokenAccount) {
    const toPublicKey = new PublicKey(recipient)
    const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, wallet, token, amount);

    const signature = await transfer(
        connection, // connection to Solana
        wallet, // the fee payer 
        fromTokenAccount.address, // the account that sends the tokens
        toTokenAccount.address, //  the account that receives the tokens 
        wallet.publicKey, // the wallet that send the transaction
        amount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL // the amount of tokens to send during the transaction 
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature });

    return signature;
}

async function disableMint() {
    await setAuthority(
        connection, // the connection to Solana
        wallet, // the fee payer
        tokenAccount.address, // the token
        wallet, // the current authority
        AuthorityType.MintTokens, // the type of authority to set
        null // this sets the mint authority to null so nobody can mint
    );
}

async function burnTokens(tokenAccount, token, amount) {
    await burn(
        connection,
        wallet,
        tokenAccount,
        token,
        wallet.publicKey,
        amount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
}

async function createToken() {
    const balance = await connection.getBalance(wallet.publicKey);

    if (balance < LAMPORTS_PER_SOL) {
        await fundWallet();
    }

    const token = await createMint(
        connection, // connection to Solana 
        wallet, // fee payer 
        wallet.publicKey, // the mint authority 
        wallet.publicKey, // the freeze authority
        9 // the number of decimals of precision our token uses (the deafault is 9)
    );

    const tokenAddress = token.toString();
    console.log(`The token was created, here is the address: ${tokenAddress}`);

    const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, wallet, token, wallet.publicKey);

    const accountAddress = tokenAccount.address.toString();
    console.log(`Created an account for the owner of the token, here is the account ${accountAddress}`);


    const initialBalance = await getAccountBalance(tokenAccount.address);
    console.log(`Initially the account had ${initialBalance} tokens`);

    await mintTo(
        connection, // connection to Solana
        wallet, // the fee payer 
        token, // the token to mint 
        tokenAccount.address, // the account that will receive the tokens
        wallet.publicKey, // the mint authority 
        10000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL // the amount of tokens that we want to mint 
    );

    const balanceAfterMint = await getAccountBalance(tokenAccount.address);
    console.log(`The account has ${balanceAfterMint} tokens after minting`);

    const transferSignature = await transferTokens(
        "GcovasTHokbR3PtA5WJ66f828fAenwSvUnv9Ju55MgCg",
        token,
        tokenAccount,
        100
    );

    console.log(
        `Transferred 100 tokens to GcovasTHokbR3PtA5WJ66f828fAenwSvUnv9Ju55MgCg, here is the signature of the transaction: ${transferSignature}`
    );

    await burnTokens(tokenAccount.address, token, 10);
    console.log(`Just burned 10 tokens`);

    const balanceAfterBurn = await getAccountBalance(tokenAccount.address);
    console.log(`The account has ${balanceAfterBurn} tokens after minting`);
}

createToken()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Done!");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `fn transferTokens` the `toTokenAccount` might be wrong.

You passed the amount into `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` you need to change it to `toTokenAccount`.

Comment: Thanks for the help